# Digital signature of a digital certificate(ex: for websites), what data is used to create the digital signature?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, digital-signature

A digital signature is used to verify a message, and is an encrypted hash of the message using a private key. In the case of an website/domain usually the private key of the intermediary CA.

From other answers, web etc the digital certificate contains the owner data, issuer data, owner public key, digital signature etc.

If the digital signature is contained by the certificate what content corresponds to the digital signature ?

Intuitive  logic - The digital signature can't be of the digital certificate because is inside the certificate and you can't sign some content and then add to the content the signature, because this will create a different signature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain the Certificate Signature Value field of a X509 Digital Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786863/explain-the-certificate-signature-value-field-of-a-x509-digital-certificate)

Comment: For a longer, but substantively consistent, example see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/manually-walking-through-the-signature-validation-of-a-certificate (disclosure: I contributed to the answer)